# Declaring output parameters for sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, output, sp-executesql

I'm trying to make a bit of SQL script that will output all the table names in a large database, along with the numbers of fields and records in each, and a list of the field names. This will allow us to focus on the tables with data, and look for field names that match from different tables, which might be appropriate places for joins.

To do this, I'm trying to write dynamic SQL that can cycle through all the tables. But I haven't been able to get sp_executesql to yield outputs that I can insert into my table variable. Here's the code I've written so far:

```
USE MITAS_TEST;
DECLARE @TablesAbstract TABLE(
    TableName VARCHAR(50),
    NumberOfFields INT,
    NumberOfRecords INT
);
DECLARE @NumberOfRowsCounted INTEGER;
SET @NumberOfRowsCounted = 0;
DECLARE @RecSql NVARCHAR(500);
SET @RecSql = 'EXECUTE(''SELECT @NumberOfRows = COUNT(*) FROM ''+@TableName)';
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(100);
SET @ParmDefinition = '@TableName NVARCHAR(100), @NumberOfRows INTEGER OUTPUT';
DECLARE @TableN NVARCHAR(100);
SET @TableN = 'MITAS_TEST.dbo.AP500';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @RecSql, 
    @ParmDefinition, 
    @TableName = @TableN,
    @NumberOfRows = @NumberOfRowsCounted OUTPUT;
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@NumberOfRows"

I would have thought it sufficed to declare `@NumberOfRows` in the `@ParmDefinition` field (based on this source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001(v=sql.90).aspx). What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The inner execute looks like:

```
EXECUTE('SELECT @NumberOfRows = COUNT(*) FROM MITA_TEST.dbo.AP500')
```

In that context, `@NumberOfRows` does not exist. You could change that to another call to sp_executesql, passing the output parameter `@NumberOfRows` down another level.

Assuming that this represents learning code, and not production. Depending on the source of @TableN, this could be susciptable to SQL injection attacks. See `quotename` in books online.